# ASPX.NET UpdateProgress not working

Tags: c#, updateprogress

I am using .NET Framework 4.0. There is a grid control on my page which takes 10-15 sec to load. I am suing telerik RadDatePicker also, so you will see reference to telerik in the code. Now, I need to use UpdateProgress control till the grid loads. The code is compiling fine but does not show the Laoding.gif. Please help

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyPage.MyReport" Title="Individual My Report" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:content id="HeaderContent" contentplaceholderid="head" runat="server">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Site.css" />
 <script language="javascript" src="Scripts/OnLoadFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMainContent" Runat="Server">


 <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 20px;" class="noPrint">
  <asp:button id="btnSaveAllTop" runat="server" text="Save All" onclick="btnSaveAll_Click" CssClass="btn"/>
  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitHomeTop" runat="server" usesubmitbehavior="true" OnClick="btnSubmitHome_Click" Text="Home" CssClass="btn" />
 </div>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="grdMyUpdatePanel" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:gridview id="grdMy" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" autogeneratecolumns="false">
  <!—Grid Cols-->
 </asp:gridview>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
 <div style="margin-top: 10px;" class="noPrint">
  <asp:button id="btnSaveAllBottom" runat="server" text="Save All" visible=false onclick="btnSaveAll_Click" CssClass="btn" />

  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitHome" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnSubmitHome_Click" Text="Home" CssClass="btn" />
 </div>

 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlUpdate" >

     <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" DisplayAfter="5000" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="grdMyUpdatePanel">
        <ProgressTemplate>
             <div class="container">
                    <div class="content">
                        <br />
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" width="20%">
                                    <asp:Image ID="img_Wait" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/Laoding.gif" />

                                </td>
                                <td width="2%">
                                </td>
                                <td align="left" width="78%">
                                    Loading...
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: DisplayAfter="5000" I added to delay the updateprogress. please ignore that

Answer (score 0):

May be image source not found.

Comment: Image is there in the images folder.